# Theorem on arithmetic of natural numbers.

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

From "Analysis I"-Herbert & Joachim:

(starting from the Peano axioms)

"There are operations addition + , multiplication · and a partial
order ≤ on N which are uniquely determined by the following conditions:
(i) Addition is associative, commutative and has the identity element 0."

$v(n)\text{ is the successor of n and v is the successor function}.$

I want to understand the structure of the proof. It starts like this:

Suppose $\star$ is a commutative operation on $\mathbb{N}$ such that

0$\star$0=0, n$\star 1$=v(n) and n$\star v(m)=v(m \star n)$ with $m,n \in \mathbb{N}.$ (1)

Let $S:=\{n\in \mathbb{N}; 0\star n=n\}$. Then $0$ is in S and if $n\in S$ then $0\star n=n$ so from (1) $0\star v(n)=v(0\star n)$ so $v(n)\in \mathbb{N}$.

---

That is just a small part of the proof. 
1. Why it was ok to suppose (1)? If I wanted to do the proof alone I would have a hard time to state them (this is in fact a definition?).
2. Here we prove that under the operation $\star$ 0 is the identity element of the operation?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) just describes how this operator is defined. You can define an operator however you like, but this describes addition as we "want" it to be.

Comment: ok, it is a definition. How about my 2nd question? I think you can post it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) just describes how this operator is defined. You can define an operator however you like, but this describes addition as we "want" it to be.

(2) Yes, $0$ becomes an identity element for this operation. But the main proof is about showing that $S$ contains all natural numbers, since $n \in S \Rightarrow v(n) \in S$ and hence if $n \in \mathbb N \Rightarrow v(n) \in \mathbb N$. (there is a small typo in your post where it says $v(v) \in \mathbb N$).